# How to assign the sensor_msgs/CameraInfo to cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, sensors, ros, msg

I would like to know what is the smartest way to assign  [const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& camInfo_msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html), to [cv::Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat).

Let's say that I wish use the parameters I**ntrinsic camera matrix float64[9]  K**  into **cv::Mat** intrK.

I  wrote the following code, it works fine, however I have no idea if it is the best way to do it. I would like to know how others solve this problem.

```
void Class::Callback(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& camInfo_msg){
  // receive the parameters
 sensor_msgs::CameraInfoPtr cameraInfoMsg = boost::make_shared<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo>(*camInfo_msg);
  // copy parameters
 cv::Mat intrK = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64FC1);
 std::vector<double> v_intrK;
  // initialize cv::Mat of correct size and vector
 v_intrK.assign((cameraInfoLMsg->K).begin(), (cameraInfoLMsg->K).end());
  // assign parameters to vector
 for (std::size_t i = 0; i < intrK.rows; i++)
   for (std::size_t j = 0; j < intrK.cols; j++)
     intrK.at<double>(i, j) = v_intrK[i*3+j];
  // assign vector to cv::Mat
```

I ask this question because when I assign the image from [const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& img_msg](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) to cv::Mat I use the [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge), so there is smart way to do it. Then maybe in camera info exists also something that I have never seen.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most compact way I found is to create a `cv::Mat` that points to the same data as `sensor_msgs::CameraInfo::K`. You can achieve this with the following code:

```
void Class::Callback(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& camInfo_msg) {
  cv::Mat intrK(3, 3, CV_64FC1, (void *) camInfo_msg->K.data());
}
```

Comment: sure, it works, smart and definitely the easiest, thanks!